# Data-Visualization Python

Tags: pandas

3. Plot 4 different line plots for the 4 companies in dataframe open_prices. Year would be on X-axis, stock price on Y axis, you will need (2,2) plot. Set figure size to 10, 8 and share X-axis for better visualization

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from nsepy import get_history
   import datetime as dt
   %matplotlib inline
   start = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
   end = dt.datetime.today()
   infy = get_history(symbol='INFY', start = start, end = end)
   infy.index = pd.to_datetime(infy.index)
   hdfc = get_history(symbol='HDFC', start = start, end = end)
   hdfc.index = pd.to_datetime(hdfc.index)
   reliance = get_history(symbol='RELIANCE', start = start, end = end)
   reliance.index = pd.to_datetime(reliance.index)
   wipro = get_history(symbol='WIPRO', start = start, end = end)
   wipro.index = pd.to_datetime(wipro.index)
   open_prices = pd.concat([infy['Open'], hdfc['Open'],reliance['Open'], 
   wipro['Open']], axis = 1)
   open_prices.columns = ['Infy', 'Hdfc', 'Reliance', 'Wipro']
   f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
   axes[0, 0].plot(open_prices.index.year,open_prices.INFY)
   axes[0, 1].plot(open_prices.index.year,open_prices.HDB)
   axes[1, 0].plot(open_prices.index.year,open_prices.TTM)
   axes[1, 1].plot(open_prices.index.year,open_prices.WIT)
   ```

Blank graph is coming.Please help....?!??

Comment: I tried running your code and got `AttributeError: 'ThreadReturns' object has no attribute 'result'` - are there any dependencies (other than pandas, numpy, matplotlib, and nsepy) we need?

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine , I have changed the following things

a) axis should be ax b) DF column names were incorrect c) for any one to try this example would also need to install lxml library

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nsepy import get_history
import datetime as dt

start = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.today()
infy = get_history(symbol='INFY', start = start, end = end)
infy.index = pd.to_datetime(infy.index)
hdfc = get_history(symbol='HDFC', start = start, end = end)
hdfc.index = pd.to_datetime(hdfc.index)
reliance = get_history(symbol='RELIANCE', start = start, end = end)
reliance.index = pd.to_datetime(reliance.index)
wipro = get_history(symbol='WIPRO', start = start, end = end)
wipro.index = pd.to_datetime(wipro.index)
open_prices = pd.concat([infy['Open'], hdfc['Open'],reliance['Open'],
wipro['Open']], axis = 1)
open_prices.columns = ['Infy', 'Hdfc', 'Reliance', 'Wipro']
print(open_prices.columns)

ax=[]
f, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharey=True)
ax[0,0].plot(open_prices.index.year,open_prices.Infy)
ax[1,0].plot(open_prices.index.year,open_prices.Hdfc)
ax[0,1].plot(open_prices.index.year,open_prices.Reliance)
ax[1,1].plot(open_prices.index.year,open_prices.Wipro)
plt.show()
```